# Hide the MasterPage menu on init (UWP only)

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

I have managed to get my Masterpage/detail working nice and it seems that on Android I don't have to change anything to get what I want but my issue is this on Windows UWP:

When the app is initiated the menu shows. I want it to be hidden. I have tried setting

```
IsPresented="False"
```

on the MasterPageItem without succes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fixes it!
this.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;